# Sampling from a exponentiated multivariate distribution with L2 norm

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I am interested in multi-variate distribution $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_d)$ with the following PDF:
$$
p(X_1, \cdots, X_d) = \frac{1}{Z}\exp\{-\beta \|X\|_2 \},
$$
where $\beta>0$ is a distribution parameter, $Z>0$ is a constant independent of $X$ and $\|X\|_2 =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2}$. Compared to a multi-variate Normal note that the $L_2$ norm of $X$ is not squared.

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a name for a distribution like this?
2. Can I sample $X$ by utilizing samples from other well-known distirbutions (e.g., multi-variate Gaussian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d=1$ this is known as *Laplace distribution*.

You can sample from it by first sampling $R = \|X\|_2$ (which will have a gamma distribution), then sampling $Y$ from a uniform distribution on the unit sphere (e.g. $Y = \frac{Z}{\|Z\|_2}$ where $Z$ has $N(0,1)$ components), and finally setting $X = RY$.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I'm not very familiar with the change-of-variable formulas but my guess is that $R$ follows a distribution of $p(R)\propto e^{-\beta R} R^{d-1}$. Is this the correct Gamma distribution for $R=\|X\|_2$, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Yiming - yes, this makes sense.